# Why does the ASP.net dropdownlist does not default to 0 if chosen jquery is used

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, jquery-chosen

I was using the Chosen Jquery which causes the dropdownlist to not update.

This is the HTML:

```
<select name="ctl00$BodyPlaceHolder$ddl1" id="ddl1" class="chose-select le">
    <option value="Select a State">Select a State</option>
    <option value="Alabama">AL</option>
    <option value="Alaska">AK</option>
    <option value="Arizona">AZ</option>
</select>
```

JavaScript which sets the selected index to 0:

```
function setSelectedIndex(dropdownlist, selVal) {
    var ddl1 = document.getElementById(dropdownlist);
    if (selVal < ddl1.selectedIndex) {
        ddl1.selectedIndex = selVal;

        $(ddl1).val(0).trigger('chosen:updated');
    }
}
```

That does the trick with one issue. The issue is once the function sets the selected index to 0, it shows the "Select an Option" as the 0 index instead of the default first option.

[image]

Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: Remove the item at the 0th index (the place holder)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to remove the `.val(0)` and it worked fine.

```
$(ddl1).trigger('chosen:updated');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
<select name="ctl00$BodyPlaceHolder$ddl1" id="ddl1" class="chose-select le">
 <option value="" disabled selected>Select a State</option>
     <option value="Alabama">AL</option>
    <option value="Alaska">AK</option>
    <option value="Arizona">AZ</option>
</select>
```

Comment: It is a ASP.net dropdownlist.

Comment: @SearchForKnowledge So?

Comment: Should not matter, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20700473/how-to-add-a-default-select-option-to-this-asp-net-dropdownlist-control

Comment: How do I make the first option disabled?

Comment: Something like this maybe? DropDownList1.Items.Insert("", "Select a State").Enabled = false;

Comment: Can't disable the first option, then the second option is auto selected.

Comment: Can you show the code you are using to create the list?

Comment: I had to remove the `.val(0)` and it works fine. Just to reply to what you are asking... here it is: `List<ListItem> lstState = new List<ListItem>(); lstState.Add(new ListItem("Select a State", "")); ddl1.Items.AddRange((lstState.ToArray()));`

Answer (score 1):

just add `data-placeholder="Choose a State"` to be like that

```
<select name="ctl00$BodyPlaceHolder$ddl1" id="ddl1" data-placeholder="Choose a State" class="chose-select le">
    <option value="Alabama">AL</option>
    <option value="Alaska">AK</option>
    <option value="Arizona">AZ</option>
</select>
```

Comment: also you can check the [custom dropdown list using chosen plugin](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/620313/Custom-ASP-NET-DropdownList-Control-Using-Chosen-j)

Comment: Thanks. How did you get your chosen to work correctly in the fiddle? I tried the same and it didn't work for me :/ http://jsfiddle.net/bpbvhsay/1/

Comment: you missed to select jquery in fiddle also you css link is broken for chosen.css

Comment: I thought u cant use HTTPS and i removed it and i think that is why :/

Comment: Silly me. I never read the warning message and pressed cancel instead. It is working now :) Btw your code also works. Thank you..