# Dynamic Dropdown issue

Tags: asp.net

Hello I am trying to implement a drop down in asp.net. The drop down is being loaded from database and is being binded with drop down. The list has various values and text. But I want to add the first option of "Please Select" which is disabled for selection at the top of drop down list. Also on binding the drop down I want to point to the value which user had previously selected so that's why I am using selectedValue option. the problem is if I add the first item as "please select" from code behind at item 0 and selectedvalue to the value stored in db it still shows me item zero" please select".

```
        DropDownList ddlMinEdit = (DropDownList)currentGrid.Rows 
      [currentGrid.EditIndex].FindControl("ddlMinEdit"); 
     ddlMinEdit.Items.Insert(0, "Select Please");        
     ddlMinEdit.Items [0].Attributes.Add("disabled", "disabled");
                    ddlMinEdit.DataSource = CList;
                    ddlMinEdit.DataTextField = "empid";
                    ddlMinEdit.DataValueField = "empname";
                    ddlMinEdit.DataBind();
                    ddlMinEdit.SelectedValue = defemp;
```

So any suggestion how do I add first item and at same time bind a list and point to selected value. thanks

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20700522) help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The order that you are doing things doesn't seems correct.  You should insert the "Select Please" after the data binding and setting the selected value:

```
DropDownList ddlMRCClinEdit = (DropDownList)currentGrid.Rows [currentGrid.EditIndex].FindControl("ddlMRCClinEdit"); 

ddlMRCClinEdit.DataSource = clinList;
ddlMRCClinEdit.DataTextField = "empid";
ddlMRCClinEdit.DataValueField = "empname";
ddlMRCClinEdit.DataBind();
ddlMRCClinEdit.SelectedValue = defemp;

ddlMRCClinEdit.Items.Insert(0, "Select Please");        
ddlMRCClinEdit.Items [0].Attributes.Add("disabled", "disabled");
```